# How to get an answer from a server to Arduino esp 8266

Tags: ip, arduino-esp8266

I have an Arduino esp 8266 code that receives data for example real-time temperature and sends the data to an external server by this code:
The code is taken from the base of [this post](https://www.instructables.com/Control-ESP8266-Over-the-Internet-from-Anywhere/)

```
           // Check WiFi connection status
          if (WiFi.status () == WL_CONNECTED) {
            HTTPClient http;
            http.begin (serverName);
// If you need an HTTP request with a content type: text / plain
http.addHeader ("Content-Type", "text / plain");
int httpResponseCode = http.POST ("**** The new data for the server ****");
                       if (httpResponseCode> 0) {
                      Serial.print ("HTTP Response code:");
                      Serial.println (httpResponseCode);
                    }
                    else {
                      Serial.print ("Error code:");
                      Serial.println (httpResponseCode);
                    }
                    // Free resources
                    http.end ();
                  }
```

The goal I am so trying to achieve right now --- as soon as the server receives the information, and it responds accordingly for example: Pin 2 - On / Off Arduino decodes the response and does its job.
My problem is that I am not able to learn **how I receive the server's response to the Arduino** (After I sent a message to the server)

Answer (score 0):

2 lines must be added to the code to get an answer to the Arduino from the server:
[I found it here:](http://%20//https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-http-get-post-arduino/)

```
                                  String payload = http.getString ();
                                  Serial.println (payload);
```

As follows:

```
          // Check WiFi connection status
          if (WiFi.status () == WL_CONNECTED) {
            HTTPClient http;
            http.begin (serverName);
 // If you need an HTTP request with a content type: text / plain
    http.addHeader ("Content-Type", "text / plain");
    int httpResponseCode = http.POST ("**** The new data for the server ****");
                       if (httpResponseCode> 0) {
                      Serial.print ("HTTP Response code:");
                      Serial.println (httpResponseCode);
                                          String payload = http.getString ();
                                          Serial.println (payload);
                    }
                    else {
                      Serial.print ("Error code:");
                      Serial.println (httpResponseCode);
                    }
                    // Free resources
                    http.end ();
                  }
```

(I'm really amazed that no one knew how to answer this simple question for me For more than two days!!!!)